# Why can I not call a form object in two events?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm making like a add contact form with two buttons, ADD CONTACT and EDIT CONTACT. When a user clicks add contact, it pops up another form where the user can add contact information.

I want to give them the option to edit that info by clicking the EDIT CONTACT button which should pop up the SAME form.

However its not letting me call the object of the form twice, saying that I cannot press the edit button after the add button.

How do I call a form object twice?

```
    //instatiating an object of the form
    FormContact contactForm = new FormContact();

    public FormManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //displaying it when the user clicks add button
        contactForm.Show();
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //trying to display it again but gives this exception

        ///System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed 
        ///object.
        ///Object name: 'FormContact'.'

        contactForm.Show();
    }

        Error:
        ///System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed 
        ///object.
        ///Object name: 'FormContact'.'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're closing the form after you've shown it.

1. You click the Show button
2. Your only instance of the form is shown
3. You close it with the X in the top corner
4. The runtime destroys the form (disposes it) after it is closed
5. You try to show it again but this this it's gone, trashed, doesn't exist any more, waiting to be garbage collected

Either make a new form each time you open it (to reduce code clutter, assign this same event handler to both button clicks, or copy paste it out twice if you want them to be coded differently eventually):

```
private void btnAddOrEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new FormContact().Show();
}
```

Or intercept the FormClosing event of the FormContact form and cancel the closing, and perform a `Hide()` instead so that instead of being destroyed your form is made invisible. It will then still exist and can be `Show()`n the next time. To handle the event, open the FormContact designer, click anywhere in the form background, click lightning bolt in properties grid, double click the FormClosing entry:

```
private void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
  e.Cancel = true;
  this.Hide();
}
```

Which method you choose depends how you want your program to behave:

If you make a new form each time, and you `Show` instead of `ShowDialog` your user could click Add twice and see two forms. Then could click Add 10 times and see 10 forms. Using ShowDialog means that the main window won't accept any more clicks until the FormContact is closed. You might or might not want this either

If you `Hide` (not close; hiding is different from closing) and `Show` the same form rather than making a new one then the user can click Add 10 times but they still only see one form

Answer (score 0):

`FormContact contactForm = new FormContact();` is a Member variable, it's scope is Private and is visible to the entire class.

After you first Show the form:

`contactForm.Show();`

The form is already showing. Therefore if you call `Show` again, it won't do anything as the instance of the form/class is already showing.

If you want to show two instances of the form, you will need to instantiate two instances eg:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormContact contactForm = new FormContact();
    contactForm.Show();
}

private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormContact contactForm = new FormContact();
    contactForm.Show();
}
```

Or make two instances of it:

```
FormContact contactForm1 = new FormContact();
FormContact contactForm2 = new FormContact();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contactForm1.Show();
}

private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contactForm2.Show();
}
```

Or add a argument in the parameter of the Constructor to indicate Add or Edit, eg:

```
public class FormContact
{
   public FormContact(int id) 
   {
     if (id > 0)
     {
        //Load contact for Editing
     }
     else
     {
        //Clear all fields for Adding
        foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
             if (ctrl Is TextBoxBase) ctrl.Text = string.Empty
             //TODO other controls types... if (ctrl Is ....
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Then you can call it passing a contactID to edit or 0 to add:

```
FormContact contactForm = new FormContact(contactID);
contactForm.Show();
```

Comment: hmm thank you i'll try it the reason i didn't do this was because i thou.ght it would create a new contactForm without the instead of calling the same one. Like because it is editing, I want the SAME info added from the add_click event to show again in the edit_Click event

Answer (score 0):

I've got another answer, in both methods simply show your form modally:

`contactForm.ShowModal();`